# Periodically download and display network-driven data using React Native and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

For the sake of example, say we're building a stock ticker application. We have a number of `<Stock>` components that each have some prop like `symbol="AAPL"`.

We also have a central Redux store of stock prices, by symbol, that gets updated periodically and "pushes" any updates out to child components. We have a `StockPriceService` which does the fetching, and has a `getPrice(symbol)` method, which is being passed down via the Context API like so:

```
// our App.js render
render() {
  return (
    <StockPriceService.Provider value={stockPriceService}>
      // Rest of view hierarchy
    </StockPriceService.Provider>
  );
}
```

What we **want** is a few features:

1. Each child `<Stock>` component to be able to render immediately, with `'--'` or similar until a network-retrieved value is available
2. The availability of network-retrieved values to be communicated through a Redux action that persists them to the store (for future offline viewing, like a weather app that shows `Last Updated: 14 minutes ago`)
3. The retrieval of stock prices should hint to the `StockPriceService` through `getPrice()` that if a value hasn't been retrieved in `>= 15 minutes`, a poll should be performed
4. If *no value* for the requested symbol is present in our Redux store, the same poll should also be attempted

So the `<Stock>` render method could look like this:

```
return (
  <Text>{this.props.symbol}: ${this.context.getPrice(this.props.symbol)}</Text>
);
```

**My Problem/Question:**
This "works", in that `getPrice()` can indeed check the local Redux store to see what's available, and return a value if it has one. But when it *doesn't*, and triggers a background download, how can the `<Stock>` component be easily signaled that it needs to re-render?

Making the `price` part of the **state** for the `<Stock>` component means the component can now automatically re-render, but how should the update for the state take place when the download completes?

If the `<Stock>` component were to retrieve its stock price directly from Redux store, the re-rendering would work properly upon the Redux action updating the Redux store, but by going around the `StockPriceSymbol`, it wouldn't have the opportunity to check if a new poll is required, or handle the appropriate business logic for fetching/storing newer/nonexistent values.

Answer (score 0):

The following should satisfy all your requirements. I'm not using the context API, just plain React+Redux. `connect` and `mapStateToProps` take care of propagating the prices and timestamps to the Stock component automatically. Each mounted Stock component will update itself every minute. That means the "updated x minutes ago" re-renders and if 15 minutes have passed, it will fetch the price again.

```
import { getPrice as getStockPrice }  from './StockPriceService';

// Assumed state and reducer structure:
/*
state = {
    stock: {
        AAPL: {
            price: 318.31,
            lastUpdated: 1580114309023
        },
        GOOGL: {
            price: 1466.17,
            lastUpdated: 1580114309045
        }
    }
}
*/

// Thunk action
const fetchPrice = (symbol) => {
    return async function(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(fetchPriceRequest(symbol));
        try {
            const { price } = await getStockPrice(symbol);
            const lastUpdated = Date.now();
            // save price and timestamp through reducer
            dispatch(fetchPriceSuccess(symbol, price, lastUpdated));
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(fetchPriceFailure(symbol));
        }
    };
};

// Selectors
const getPrice = (state, symbol) => (state.stock[symbol] && state.stock[symbol].price) || '--';
const getLastUpdated = (state, symbol) => (state.stock[symbol] && state.stock[symbol].lastUpdated) || 'never';

// Creating a connected Stock component
const Stock = ({ symbol, price, lastUpdated, fetchPrice }) => {
    const [updatedWhen, setUpdatedWhen] = useState('never');
    const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // On first render during entire app runtime, fetch price immediately
        if (price === '--' || lastUpdated === 'never') {
            fetchPrice(symbol);            
        }

        // Check every minute for updates
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            const now = Date.now();

            // TODO: some nicer date formatting here, I left this part out.
            setUpdatedWhen(now - lastUpdated);

            const isPriceOutdated = lastUpdated + (15 * 60 * 1000) <= now;
            if (price === '--' || lastUpdated === 'never' || isPriceOutdated) {
                fetchPrice(symbol);
            }
        }, 60 * 1000);
        setIntervalID(id);

        return function cleanup() {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <Text>{symbol}: {price}} (last updated: {lastUpdated} {updatedWhen})</Text>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    const { symbol } = ownProps;
    return {
        price: getPrice(state, symbol),
        lastUpdated: getLastUpdated(state, symbol);
    };
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchPrice
};


// Use this connected component in your app
const ConnectedStock = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToprops)(Stock);
```